# Return input as a partial fraction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mathematics

I need to write a function that, when given an input (string, float, or int), returns that input as a reduced partial fraction, and it needs to accept a wide array of inputs:

```
1.5 =>  "1 1/2"
5/2 => "2 1/2"
"1/3" => "1/3"
5 => "5"
"6 1/3" => "6 1/3"
0 => "0"
```

I've written this function using the Rational class, but was wondering if there were a better, more elegant solution:

```
def format_partial_fraction(fraction)
  if fraction.include? "/" # to handle "6 1/3" => "6 1/3" (or maybe I'll just trust user input in this case)
    fraction = fraction.split(" ").inject{|sum,x| sum.to_r + x.to_r }
  end

  rational = fraction.to_r
  if rational == 0
    return "0"
  elsif rational < 1 # e.g. "1/3"
    rational.to_s
  else # e.g. "3 1/2" or just "3"
    rational.to_i.to_s + ( rational%1 == 0 ? "" : " " + (rational%1).to_s)
  end
end
```

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 3.2.13

Comment: I misread the title at first.  I was disappointed when I found that no partial _function_ is involved :)  Still, good question.

Comment: f you are satisfied with any of the answers, you should select the one that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-string input can lead to surprising results:

```
p (5/2).to_r #=> (2/1), integer division performed first
p (1.1).to_r #=> (2476979795053773/2251799813685248),  float can not be represented in binary
```

The last case is prevented by:

```
p 1.1.to_s.to_r #=> (11/10)
```

So I'd change `rational = fraction.to_r` to `rational = fraction.to_s.to_r`.  But the first case is only handled correctly if it is a string to begin with:

```
p "5/2".to_r #=> (5/2)
```

I don't think there is a remedy for that, except accepting string or float input input only.

Comment: Right. If the method-caller passes in `5/2` as an integer, there's nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
fraction = fraction.split(" ").inject{|sum,x| sum.to_r + x.to_r }
```

can also be expressed like this:

```
fraction = fraction.split(" ").map(&:to_r).inject(:+)
```

this:

```
rational.to_i.to_s + ( rational%1 == 0 ? "" : " " + (rational%1).to_s)
```

is a bit long, and repeats the expression `rational%1`.  I'd use a small private method to clean it up a bit:

```
rational.to_i.to_s + fractional_part_to_s(rational % 1)

...

def fraction_part_to_s(f)
  if fractional_part == 0
    ""
  else
    fractional_part.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: I like your first suggestion but I prefer the compactness of the original over your 2nd suggestion

Comment: @Jonah, Although I am not a fan of the trinary operator, it is a reasonable choice, and would serve just as well there.

Comment: on 2nd thought i do like giving that portion a name. i just really dislike full if else statements.  you could do `return f.to_s unless f == 0; ""`

Comment: @Jonah, There are many ways to skin this cat